# How to fix Minecraft not reacting to pressed scroll button?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I used to be able to open a chest and press the scroll button while hovering over an item stack and it would send one of them in the chest. But when I try doing this now, it doesn't do anything. I tried looking online, no help.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  As it stands it is very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

This feature you are describing is part of the InventoryTweaks mod. It's not in vanilla Minecraft.

EDIT: I read your question wrong. It does nothing, because you need to be in creative mode (it turns one item into a stack).

Comment: The only mod I ever use is the Optifine mod and I used to be able to use it.

Comment: @Skyler: What you described isn't, and never was a vanilla behavior. Middle-click on item/stack in inventory in creative grabs a stack of its clones, and in survival does nothing.